# Is the a ScriptEngine or eval()-like function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, eval

In Java, we can build up expressions to be called using `ScriptEngine`.  This is nice for building up frameworks based on a common naming convention.  In JavaScript, there is of course `eval()`.  Does Swift have some sort of mechanism for evaluating a string which contains a swift expression?  I'm aware that this could be potentially abused; however, it would simplify my present development.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Swift is a compiled language, and the runtime doesn't include the compiler.  The iOS SDK doesn't provide a way to evaluate run-time Swift code.

You can execute JavaScript using JavaScriptCore, and JavaScriptCore makes it pretty easy to expose Swift objects and functions to the script.  Maybe that will help you.