# Is it possible to evaluate a var/let with Swift?

Tags: swift, eval, evaluate

Based upon this question: << [Is the a ScriptEngine or eval()-like function in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244069/is-the-a-scriptengine-or-eval-like-function-in-swift) >> I'm assuming the following would not work in Swift:

```
private let BROWN_COLOUR: UIColor = UIColor.brownColor()

...

var colourName: String = "BROWN"
var colour = self[ colourName + "_COLOUR" ] as UIColor!
```

Correct or not?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: what is Self in this context ?

Comment: A class, let is declared at initialisation, the other code runs later.

Comment: why not use the names as keys in a dictionary and have the colours as the values?

Comment: You don't need to go full `eval` here. Unless I am missing something, a simple key-value lookup would work.

Comment: Of course. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that out of the box. You can, however, use [keyed subscription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html) to solve this. Or even easier: use a dictionary to store your values and query that.

But if the object derives from `NSObject` and the instance variables are marked with `@objc`, you *can* query these instance variables with [`valueForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/).